# Getting last 10 product view by user id

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mongodb

How can i getting last 10 product views by user(with userid) in json format.

My Event Class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Document(collection = "events")
public class Event {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String event;
    private String messageid;
    private String userid;
    private ProductProperties properties;
    private Context context;
    private String timestamp;

}
```

My ProductProperties Class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class ProductProperties {

    private String productid;

}
```

My Context Class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Context {

    private String source;

}
```

My Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface EventRepository extends MongoRepository<Event, String> {
    List<Event> findByUseridAndEventOrderByTimestampDesc(String userId, String event, Pageable pageable);

}
```

My Service Method:

```
public List<Event> getLast10ProductViewsByUserId(String userId) {
        return eventRepository.findByUseridAndEventOrderByTimestampDesc(userId, "ProductView", PageRequest.of(0, 10));
    }
```

My Database tables example:

[image]

I want result with a get request like this:

```
{
    "user-id": "user-34",
    "products": ["a","b","c","d"."e"],
    "type" : "personalized"
}
```

I tried pagable but i guess i could not make it.

Comment: If you don’t need to determine that size (10) dynamically, try findFirst10ByXYZ:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result